# What kind of phrasal verbs could be inverted to make an inverted sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage, verbs, phrasal-verbs, inversion

I'm learning the inverted sentences in English, actually I'm a new hand to this.

There are one or two examples of inverted sentences in which the inverted parts are its phrasal verbs in my book.

> **Away** went the time when you understood it.

> **Up** jumped the frog.

May you tell me under what kind of occasion the phrasal verb could be inverted?

And further, are phrasal verbs productive at the level of inversion linguistically?

---

Update:

I found other examples, and the book told me they should be inverted thoroughly when the adverbs expressing orientations such as *out*, *in*, *up*, *down* in the sentence starters. If the subjects are personal pronouns they need not be inverted.

> **In** came Mr. White.
>
> **Up** went the arrow into the air.
>
> **Away** went the boy.

Comment: I believe I hear your inverted sentences as no longer being the phrasal verbs, for example, interpreting "up jumped the frog" as "the frog jumped upward". But I wouldn't be surprised if others hear it as a poetic/archaic version of the phrasal verb.

Comment: @DanGetz Speaking of 'the frog', I think so. Or rather, depending on my sprachgefühl of English, I tend to understand it as you do.

Comment: The inversion is just a stylistic device used in storytelling to emphasise the movement by putting the adverb indicating direction first.

Comment: @KateBunting Really? In other styles and spoken language don't native speakers use the inversion?

Comment: My brother told me this is called 'V2 word order', I'm going to research it on Wikipedia.

Comment: _Mr. White came in_ is just a basic statement. To make it seem more lively (perhaps Mr. White is an important person, his arrival is long-expected or unexpected, for example) we might invert it in either a spoken or written narrative.

Comment: I agree with Dan Getz.  I don't think any of the examples include phrasal verbs.  Some would be ambiguous in the uninverted form, such as "Mr. Smith came in", but in the inverted form are clearly not phrasal verbs.  "In came Mr. Smith" could not mean *Mr. Smith made a visit to the office* (which is one possible meaning of "Mr. Smith came in").

Comment: I should warn, all of these convey a rather literary tone; they would be a bit odd in spoken conversation. And overdone, they run the risk of sounding like the *Star Wars* character Yoda ("Away put your weapon!").

Comment: See also at → https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English#Locative_inversion